# jQuery resizable handle inside child

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am receiving this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ownerDocument' of undefined

when I try to place my resizable handle inside a child of the container I am trying to resize.

[image: Code]

As you can see, it is currently inside the *controls* div, however the handle is meant to resize the .ui-widget container, however it is instead throwing the above error.

If I move the handle outside of the *controls* div however, it works fine.

Why is this happening? Is there a workaround?

Current jQuery code:

```
$("div.ui-widget").resizable({
    handles: {
        'se': 'div.ui-resizable-se'
    },
    start: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).addClass("dragging");
    },
    stop: function(e, ui) {
        $(ui.helper).removeClass("dragging");
        oldWidget.saveState($(ui.helper), 'resize');
    }
});
```

Comment: In your console, from which file comes the error? And which line?

Comment: jquery.js:2 which i have not touched (its the main jquery file)

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution myself.

It seems that it was the JqueryUI version causing it! I was using 1.11.x and after reverting to 1.10.4 the problem is gone and it functions correctly!

Any reasons why are greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have a reason but I do have a fix. I replaced: `handles: { se: '.resize-handle' }` with `handles: { se: $elem.find('.resize-handle') }` to give it a JQuery object rather than a selector and it worked in 1.11.