# Jquery ui Resizable handle not working in append element function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, resize, append

I'm using jQuery UI Resizable, and I will use [custom handles](http://api.jqueryui.com/resizable/#option-handles). To do that, I follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15923891/resizable-handles-with-jqueryui) but I get same problem like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641697/jquery-resizable-handle-inside-child), so I try their answer but still not working. Can someone help to make this working?  This is my fiddle problem https://jsfiddle.net/suiko/155zzw2p/3/

```
$(document).on({mouseenter: function (e) {
    var elmnt_col = $(this);
    $(elmnt_col).append("<div class='overlay' id='overlay-column'><div class='overlay-menu-action' id='overlay-menu-column'><div class='overlay-label' id='overlay-label-column'>Column</div></div></div>");

    $(elmnt_col).find('#overlay-column').append("<div class='resize-handle ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e' id='right-resize-handle'></div>");
    $(elmnt_col).resizable({
        handles: {
            e: '#right-resize-handle'
        }
    });
}, mouseleave: function (e) {
        $("#overlay-column").remove();
    }}, ".custom-column");
```